# Reading numbers from console until input isn't a number

Tags: beginner, console, f#

I want to read N numbers (Nmax = 100) from console into a list. N is not known, but the first input that is not a number may break the reading process... However the solution should be as simple as possible, so I just read 100 lines:

```
let numbers = [1..100]
        |> List.map (fun x -> Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine())) 
        |> List.filter (fun (isNum, num) -> isNum)
        |> List.map (fun (isNum, num) -> num)
```

Is there a simpler (less code) solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does not read numbers from the "*console until input isn't a number*", but reads 100 inputs strings from the console and returns those that can be converted to integers.

If you want to read numbers from the console "*until input isn't a number*", you could do something like this:

```
let numbers1 max = seq {for x in 1..max do yield Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine()) }
                  |> Seq.takeWhile (fun (b, x) -> b) 
                  |> Seq.map (fun (b, x) -> x)
```

or

```
let numbers2 max = seq {for x in 1..max do yield Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine()) }
                    |> Seq.takeWhile (fun (b, x) -> b) 
                    |> Seq.map (fun (b, x) -> x)
                    |> Seq.toList
```

if you want to defer the return of each input to after the last valid input has been entered.

Comment: `Seq.takeWhile` makes it! I hoped there is an even shorter solution... but that one work fine, thanks :)